# Mobile SDK authentication on iOS via native browser

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, login-errors

We want to activate "Use the native browser for user authentication on iOS", but we are facing an error during the sign-in process. Our application uses mobile SDK, and without this option, the login works well.

The login process starts with the following URL, and I removed all sensitive tokens or ids.
https://edwards--mdmtest.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=myapp:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done&display=touch&response_type=code&state=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&scope=web%20api%20refresh_token&code_challenge=YYYYY

As another step, the sign-in process is trying to obtain an access token.
POST https://edwards--mdmtest.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
format=json&redirect_uri=myapp:///mobilesdk/detect/oauth/done&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&device_id=DEVICE_ID&code_verifier=VERIFICATION_CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&code=CODE_XYZ

But from the server, we get the error.
400 Bad Request
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"invalid client credentials"}

Could you advise us on what we should change in the mobile app to be able to sign in with this option? Are there any special settings for the mobile SDK to support this authentication via the native browser?

Many thanks,
Petr

Comment: Not aware of any special settings for using this - Be worth reviewing your OAuth scopes (maybe add web?), and after changing any setting in the connected app you do need to wait a good 10 minutues for things to update.

Comment: Have you read this documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/auth_advanced_using.htm In particular, have you made sure "Make sure that Require Secret for Web Server Flow" is not selected in your Connected App Settings?